Why is this Perl CGI script failing to run with a Permission denied error
This question is related to this question
Can someone please explain what is going on here?
[User@redhat cgi-bin]$ pwd
/var/www/cgi-bin

[User@redhat cgi-bin]$ ll -a Test.cgi
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root      86 Jul 10 16:37 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root   root      61 Jul 10 18:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache 79 Jul 11 09:30 Test.cgi

[User@redhat cgi-bin]$ perl -T ./Test.cgi
Content-type: text/html

Hello World!

[User@redhat cgi-bin]$ cat Test.cgi
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello World!";

[User@redhat cgi-bin]$ ./Test.cgi
-bash: ./Test.cgi: Permission denied

I think whatever is causing this is the root reason of the failure of the CGI script execution on the question linked above.
(The SELinux in this system is set to Permissive)

Is /var/www/cgi-bin on a different filesystem from /? If so, what are the mount options? Add the output of findmnt --target /var/www/cgi-bin.

That was the answer @larsks ! Make it official to mark it as answered.

I suspect that your /var/www/cgi-bin directory exists on a filesystem mounted with the noexec option. You can diagnose this using the findmnt command, like this:
findmnt --target /var/www/cgi-bin

This will produce output something like:
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/vda1 xfs    rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota

If you see the noexec option in the third field, that's your problem. You can fix that by either changing the mount options or by moving your cgi scripts to a different location.
